# Can Gomory-Hu tree algorithm be applied to graphs with more than one connected component?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, minimum-cuts

If I have an undirected graph with more than one connected component, can I apply the Gomory-Hu algorithm directly on the entire graph or do I have to apply it separately to each component?